# The INSERT Statement confllicted with the foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, conflict

I came across this problem. Could somebody push me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: here is the same code as displayed on the image:

```
DROP DATABASE [opdracht casus theater]
CREATE DATABASE [opdracht casus theater]
DROP TABLE Prijzen
drop table bezetting
drop table Uitvoering

use [opdracht casus theater]

CREATE TABLE Person
(
Persoonnummer   int identity    not null,
Achternaam      varchar(50)     not null,
TussenVoegsels  varchar(50)     null,
Voorletters     varchar(5)      not null,
Geslacht        varchar(1)      not null,
Adres           varchar(50)     not null,
Postcose        char(7)         not null,
Woonplaats      varchar(50)     not null,
Telefoonnummer  varchar(20)     null,
Mailadres       varchar(50)     null,
PRIMARY KEY(Persoonnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Reservering
(
Reserveringnummer   int identity    not null,
Persoonnummer       int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(Persoonnummer)            not null,
Betaald             bit             not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Reserveringnummer),
);

CREATE TABLE Bezetting
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer) not null,
Uitvoeringnummer    int                                                         not null,
Rijnummer           numeric(2,0)                                                not null,
Stoelnummer         numeric(4,0)                                                not null,
Reserveringnummer   int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Reservering(Reserveringnummer)   not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Uitvoeringnummer, Rijnummer, Stoelnummer),
);

CREATE TABLE Uitvoering
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer) not null,
Uitvoeringnummer    int                                                         not null,       
Zaalnaam            varchar(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Zaal(Zaalnaam)           not null,
BeginDatumTijd      datetime                                                    not null,
EindDatumTijd       datetime,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Uitvoeringnummer),

);

CREATE TABLE Voorstelling
(
Voorstellingnummer  int identity    not null,
Titel               varchar(50)     not null,
Uitvoerende         varchar(50)     not null,
Beschrijving        varchar(255),   
Plaatje             image,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Zaal
(
Zaalnaam    Varchar(11)     not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Zaalnaam),
);

CREATE TABLE Prijzen
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer)     not null,
Rangnaam            varchar(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rang(Rangnaam)                not null,
Prijs               numeric(5,2)                                                    not null
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Rangnaam),                                              
);

CREATE TABLE Rang
(
Rangnaam            varchar(6)      not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Rangnaam),
);

CREATE TABLE Stoel
(
Zaalnaam            varchar(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Zaal(Zaalnaam)           not null,
Rijnummer           numeric(2,0)                                                not null,
Stoelnummer         numeric(4,0)                                                not null,
Rangnaam            varchar(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rang(Rangnaam)            not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Zaalnaam, Rijnummer, Stoelnummer),
);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [opdracht casus theater] ON; 
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer, Titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) VALUES('36','Most Wanted','Najib Amhali','Een erg leuke Voorstelling');
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer, Titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) Values('40', 'Ballyhoo!', 'Ashton Brothers', 'Mix van caberet, acrobatiek en slapstick');
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(voorstellingnummer, titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) VALUES('42', 'Onderweg','BoudeWijn de Groot', 'Theaterconcert van de godfather van het nederlandstalig lied');
```

Comment: Can't read anything in your code preview.. can you copy and paste codes here directly plz

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my computer .
Your problem was referencing table on foreign key before it created.

```
DROP DATABASE [opdracht casus theater]
CREATE DATABASE [opdracht casus theater]
DROP TABLE Prijzen
drop table bezetting
drop table Uitvoering

use [opdracht casus theater]

CREATE TABLE Person
(
Persoonnummer   int identity    not null,
Achternaam      varchar(50)     not null,
TussenVoegsels  varchar(50)     null,
Voorletters     varchar(5)      not null,
Geslacht        varchar(1)      not null,
Adres           varchar(50)     not null,
Postcose        char(7)         not null,
Woonplaats      varchar(50)     not null,
Telefoonnummer  varchar(20)     null,
Mailadres       varchar(50)     null,
PRIMARY KEY(Persoonnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Reservering
(
Reserveringnummer   int identity    not null,
Persoonnummer       int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(Persoonnummer)            not null,
Betaald             bit             not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Reserveringnummer),
);
CREATE TABLE Voorstelling
(
Voorstellingnummer  int identity    not null,
Titel               varchar(50)     not null,
Uitvoerende         varchar(50)     not null,
Beschrijving        varchar(255),   
Plaatje             image,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Bezetting
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer) not null,
Uitvoeringnummer    int                                                         not null,
Rijnummer           numeric(2,0)                                                not null,
Stoelnummer         numeric(4,0)                                                not null,
Reserveringnummer   int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Reservering(Reserveringnummer)   not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Uitvoeringnummer, Rijnummer, Stoelnummer),
);

CREATE TABLE Zaal
(
Zaalnaam    Varchar(11)     not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Zaalnaam),
);

CREATE TABLE Uitvoering
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer) not null,
Uitvoeringnummer    int                                                         not null,       
Zaalnaam            varchar(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Zaal(Zaalnaam)           not null,
BeginDatumTijd      datetime                                                    not null,
EindDatumTijd       datetime,
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Uitvoeringnummer),

);


CREATE TABLE Rang
(
Rangnaam            varchar(6)      not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Rangnaam),
);

CREATE TABLE Prijzen
(
Voorstellingnummer  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer)     not null,
Rangnaam            varchar(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rang(Rangnaam)                not null,
Prijs               numeric(5,2)                                                    not null
PRIMARY KEY(Voorstellingnummer, Rangnaam),                                              
);



CREATE TABLE Stoel
(
Zaalnaam            varchar(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Zaal(Zaalnaam)           not null,
Rijnummer           numeric(2,0)                                                not null,
Stoelnummer         numeric(4,0)                                                not null,
Rangnaam            varchar(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rang(Rangnaam)            not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Zaalnaam, Rijnummer, Stoelnummer),
);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT VOORSTELLING ON; 
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer, Titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) VALUES('36','Most Wanted','Najib Amhali','Een erg leuke Voorstelling');
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(Voorstellingnummer, Titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) Values('40', 'Ballyhoo!', 'Ashton Brothers', 'Mix van caberet, acrobatiek en slapstick');
INSERT INTO Voorstelling(voorstellingnummer, titel, Uitvoerende, Beschrijving) 
VALUES('42', 'Onderweg','BoudeWijn de Groot', 'Theaterconcert van de godfather van het nederlandstalig lied');
```